# Scaling desktop screen

Tags: 12.10, display

I am using Panasonic TV 42 Inch as monitor via HDMI port and my desktop is stretching 
out scaled and some parts of desktop are not visible. I need help to scale down the horizontal and vertical scaling using ubuntu os settings as i cant do it using TV settings.
kindly help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This not a real answer but more like a tip. What you are experiencing is “underscan” and problem that is related to it is “overscan” (this is when the desktop would be smaller that the screen). So these are the words to google.
It is a common problem with some graphic cards and the TV's that just don't want to get along. If you  are using proprietary drivers then just go through the display settings and you should some settings for it there. If you are using open source drivers it will be more hard core xorg tweaking.
Sorry, that I can't be of more help right now but hopefully these keywords can help you find more information about the problem and the ways to solve it.